# efficient implementation of a tensor dot product in matlab

Tags: matlab, multiplication, dot-product

In MATLAB I have a series of 2x2 matrices stacked into a 3D tensor and I'd like to perform a matrix multiplication for each instance of matrices.

so my C = A * B is defined as

```
C_ijk = sum(a_ilk * b_ljk, over all l)
```

my current implementation looks like this

```
    function mats = mul3D(A, B)
        % given a list of 2D matrices (e.g. rotation matrices) applies
        % the matrix product for each instance along the third dimension
        % mats(:,:,i) = A(:,:,i) * B(:,:,i) for all i
        % for this to succeed matrix dimensions must agree.
        mats = zeros(size(A,1), size(B,2), size(B,3));
        for i=1:size(B, 3)
            mats(:,:,i) = A(:,:,i) * B(:,:,i);
        end
    end
```

which is very easy to read but I remember someone saying that MATLAB doesn't like for-loops.

So can you think of a better implementation that doesn't consume more memory than this one while being faster? my code spends about 50% of the run time in this for loop.

**edit**

thanks for your suggestions. Unfortunately I'm unable to introduce new dependencies to 3rd party code.

Based on your questions I had the idea of exploiting the 2 x 2 x n structure of the tensors. My latest implementation looks like this:

```
    function mats = mul3D(A, B)
        % given a list of 2D matrices (e.g. rotation matrices) applies
        % the matrix product for each instance along the third dimension
        % mats(:,:,i) = A(:,:,i) * B(:,:,i) for all i
        % for this to succeed matrix dimensions must agree.
        mats = zeros(size(A,1), size(B,2), size(B,3));

        mats(1,1,:) = A(1,1,:) .* B(1,1,:) + A(1,2,:) .* B(2,1,:);
        mats(2,1,:) = A(2,1,:) .* B(1,1,:) + A(2,2,:) .* B(2,1,:);
        if(size(mats,2) > 1)
            mats(1,2,:) = A(1,1,:) .* B(1,2,:) + A(1,2,:) .* B(2,2,:);
            mats(2,2,:) = A(2,1,:) .* B(1,2,:) + A(2,2,:) .* B(2,2,:);
        end
    end
```

any further suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: For arbitrary sizes it could be done with `bsxfun` and `permute`, but it will take more memory and it's not clear that it will be faster. In recent Matlab versions loops are not as slow as they used to be. If some size is fixed, perhaps that can be exploited. What sizes (dimensions) are fixed and what's their value?

Comment: What are the typical shapes of `A` and `B`?

Comment: I found optimized library here: [link](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/62382-matrix-multiply-slices-of-3d-matricies). I had problems building it.

Comment: It the following code `mats(:,:,i) = A(:,:,i) * B(:,:,i)` defined as "dot-product'?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you use `mtimesx`.
Refer here: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/62382-matrix-multiply-slices-of-3d-matricies

`mtimesx` uses an optimized **mex file** to do *"Matrix multiply slices of 3d Matricies"*.

`mtimesx` uses [BLAST library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms) (BLAST library is part of Matlab installation).

Download **mtimesx** source code from here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25977-mtimesx-fast-matrix-multiply-with-multi-dimensional-support

I had a problem building the mex file in Matalb r2014b.
The problem is that Matlab versions above r2014a lack the file `mexopts.bat`.
The mex building script uses `mexopts.bat`.

I solved it by downloading `mexopts.bat`.
I am using compiler of Visual Studio 2010, and found matching `mexopts.bat` here: http://www.dynare.org/DynareWiki/ConfigureMatlabWindowsForMexCompilation

I copied `mexopts.bat` to local folder: `c:\Users\`*Rotem*`\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2014b\`

After all that `mtimesx` is working quite well...
Using the mex file should be much faster then using for loop.